# how can I integrate bootstrap with jsf?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsf, primefaces, responsive

What's the best way to use JSF with bootstrap-framework?

I am trying to build a responsive site. I know jsf and primefaces but doesnot know how to integrate bootstrap in jsf.

Are there some begginer tutorial about how can I integrate bootstrap with jsf?

Comment: Please elaborate more on the problems you are facing while integrating Bootstrap with JSF

Comment: http://www.bootsfaces.net/

Comment: You should check this out: http://blog.hatemalimam.com/jsf-and-twitter-bootstrap-integration/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside Your `src>main>webapp` place the bootstrap folder and

You can render bootstrap from outside web-inf folder

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

for inside web-inf folder do this

```
<link href="#{request.contextPath}/css/bootstrap.css"
          rel="stylesheet" />
```

or simply can do this also

```
<h:outputScript name="css/bootstrap.css" />
```

but bootstrap and jsf or primefaces is hard to work together maybe look at the `Bootsfaces`. [here](http://showcase.bootsfaces.net/integration/PrimeFaces.jsf)

for individual bootstrap 3 tutorials

[Bootstrap](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/)